# I need to take some XML/SP Services code and rewrite using ajax

Tags: sharepoint-designer, ajax, xml

I was given this XML code and they would like to convert it into ajax code. I have never worked with XML/SP Services and I am not sure if what I have done is right.

```
var accID = 'AIRLINES';
var searchVal = '';
$(document).ready(function () {

    tdResults = $().SPServices.SPGetListItemsJson({
        webURL: "/airport/business",
        listName: "TenantDirectory",
        viewName: "",
        CAMLQuery: "",
        CAMLViewFields: "",
        CAMLRowLimit: "",
        CAMLQueryOptions: "",
        changeToken: "",
        contains: "",
        mapping: {
            ows_Title: {
                mappedName: "Title",
                objectType: "Text"
            },
            ows_Address: {
                mappedName: "Address",
                objectType: "Text"
            },
            ows_Numbers: {
                mappedName: "Numbers",
                objectType: "Text"
            },
            ows_Categories: {
                mappedName: "Categories",
                objectType: "Text"
            },
            ows_link: {
                mappedName: "Link",
                objectType: "Text"
            },
            ows_ID: {
                mappedName: "ID",
                objectType: "Text"
            },

        },
        mappingOverrides: null,
        debug: false
    });
```

```
var tdResults = $.ajax({
    url: apiUrl1,
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json; odata=verbose'
    },
    success: function (data) {

        var items = data.d.results;

        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

            var title = items[i].Title;
            var address = items[i].Address;
            console.log(address)
            var number = items[i].Numbers;
            var categories = items[i].Categories;
            var id = items[i].ID;
            var link = items[i].Link;

        } // this ends for loop

        /*mappingOverrides: null,
        debug: false*/

    }, // this ends success function

    error: function(data) {
        console.log('Error: ' + data);
    }
}); //end of ajax
```

Comment: Can you be more specific, whats your question? The code didn't worked?

Comment: @ThalesChemenian I have the entire ajax code but somebody asked me to break it up into pieces because it is a long code. So for this part I want to know if the ajax code is reflects what is written on the XML code.